# Elasticsearch: merge terms query and match query

Tags: elasticsearch, match

Assume, my table has 2 fields: user_name and age
I want to check list user name:[john, mary, jim] and that user has "age" is 20. How can I do?
I think I will merge 2 queries below:

- Term query:
      {
        "terms" : {
          "user" : [ "john", "mary", "jim" ]
        }
      }
- And match query:

  {
      "query": {
          "match": {
             "age": 20
          }
      }
  }

But I not sure. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `terms` query seems appropriate for the name. However, I would recommend a `term` filter for the "age", since it is a numeric value. Generally, the `match` query is for `analyzed` fields that you plan to do full-text searching on.

As an example, you can link your two search criteria together using a `filtered` query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "terms": {
          "user_name": ["john","mary","jim"]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "age": 20
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Another possibility is to combine your search criteria using a `bool` query. For example.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "user_name": ["john","mary","jim"]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "age": 20
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Have a look at the [documentation for Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) here.

Comment: Thanks so much. I got it :)

Comment: @TriPham glad I could help!